# How could a buffer overﬂow attack on the updateConfigParams() function be exploited to disable the program?

Tags: c, buffer, buffer-overflow

**Considering the following function**

```
void updateConfigParams( void ) {
    char buffer [512];
    int i = 0;

    while (( c = readFromWireless ()) != NULL) 
    {
        buffer [ i ] = c;
        i += 1; 
    } 
    writeConfigParams ( buffer );
}
```

how could a buﬀer overﬂow attack on the updateConfigParams() function be exploited to disable the program?.

Comment: if `readFromWireless()` returns a `char` or an `int` (as suggested in the assignment `buffer[i] = c`) you can not compare it with `NULL` (a pointer)

Comment: It's only seven lines long. Can you really not be bothered to format your code properly?

Comment: Sounds like a homework question.

Comment: As stated by previous comments `NULL` should be replaced by `0`. Now to answer the question: What do you think happens if the `readFromWireless` function returns a value different from `0` let's say 600 times in a row?

Comment: @MichaelWalz AFAIK, *accessing* one element past the the last index of `buffer` is undefined behaviour.

Comment: @babon yes it is, but undefined behaviour can be used to do all sorts of strange things...

Comment: @MichaelWalz Well, considering the above example, we can't definitely say that `buffer[513]` will be written to. The program might crash / stop before any data is written. My point is that we can't be sure that we can exploit this.

Comment: @babon we cannot be sure that this can be exploited, but _potentially_ it could.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Agreed.

Comment: @babon anyway if you fill up the buffer far enough, there is a big chance that the program will crash at some point thus disabling it (see question title).

Answer (score 0):

In the example `i` is an integer and lets say it occupies 4 bytes.

Assume your memory looks like this:

```
    0          1                  511       512    513    514    515   ...
buffer[0] | buffer[1] | ... | buffer[511] | i[0] | i[1] | i[2] | i[3] | ...
```

In the while loop you write something to the memory at position `buffer[i]`.

```
while (( c = readFromWireless ()) != 0) 
{
    buffer [ i ] = c;
    i += 1; 
}
```

When you write something to `buffer[511]` (512th iteration) your memory looks as follows:

```
   0        1              511     512    513    514    515
value0 | value1 | ... | value511 | 0xff | 0x01 | 0x00 | 0x00 | ...
```

Note that indicies 512 and 513 represent the value of variable `i` : `i = 511`

In case you received more than 512 bytes you will overwrite variable  `i`, thus in 513th iteration you will write to the memory of `i[0]` (index 512).

```
   0        1              511        512     513    514    515
value0 | value1 | ... | value511 | value512 | 0x01 | 0x00 | 0x00 | ...
```

lets say that `value512` is `0xff` so we do not change anything.

In 514th iteration you will overwrite memory at the position of `i[1]` (index 513).

```
   0        1              511        512       513      514    515
value0 | value1 | ... | value511 | value512 | value513 | 0x00 | 0x00 | ...
```

In 515th iteration you will write `value514` to the memory of `buffer[i]`. But now `i = (value513 << 8) | value512` so you may try to write to the memory area where your process does not have rights to write.